# Free software to analyse voice pitch

Tags: voice, software

I'd like to analyse recordings to see when and how much out of tune I sing, in order to practice my singing. I'm aware of expensive solutions such as Melodyne, but is there any free way to do that?

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Hi Anna. Unfortunately, asking for software recommendations is off-topic here. You may be able to ask on the [Software Recs SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you can format your question to [their standards](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). To find out more about this site [take the tour](http://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [FAQ](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can download a choice of free tuner apps for any computer, tablet or phone.

I should warn you - it will be interesting to sing a slow scale and see if you're on pitch.  You'll get less useful information about real-life singing.   So tune your ear in by singing sustained notes into the meter, then LISTEN to your recorded voice to criticise it.